# Image downloaded using powershell missing data in properties

Tags: powershell, download

I'm trying to use powershell to download an image to deploy as a wallpaper to Pro edition computers, given that GPO can only deploy wallpapers to enterprise edition.

I have tried the 2 following commands:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url -OutFile $output
```

and

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output)
```

the files download without an error, however when trying to open the images, it says that the format is unsupported. I have tried downloading as both .jpg and .png without success. I have checked the item properties and found that, for some reason, when it downloads with powershell, the downloaded image is missing certain details in properties:

**Image downloaded with powershell:**

[image]

**Original image when downloaded manually from the same source**

[image]

I have also observed that the size of the file downloaded via powershell is approx. 7 times smaller than when downloaded manually.
I have tried using several image hosting websites, as well as different download directories, with the same results every time.

Full code for download is as below:

```
#Open the folder in Windows Explorer under C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\***
########################################################################################

Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
$path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData') + "\***"

If(!(test-path $path))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
########################################################################################


#Download the image to user profile
########################################################################################
$url = "{image URL}"
$output = $path + "\Background.jpg"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that it was downloading the entire webpage HTML with the image extension, used the open image in new tab and used the i.***.com***.jpg as the url and it has downloaded the image correctly.